# how to give labels in subplot in matlab on an axis

Tags: matlab, label, subplot

I have this script in which 8 rows are plotted and giving each row's y axis label c1, c2, c3, c4 etc.

```
figure
for i=1:6

   subplot(6,1,i)

   plot (sin(1:100)*10^(i-1))

   y_titre=sprintf('c%d',i)

   ylabel(y_titre,'Fontname','Times new roman','FontSize',10,'fontweight','b')

end
```

My problem is that besides giving above label to each figure, i also have to give the overall label on y-axis. How  could this be done, i am not knowing???
Kindly suggest me... thanx

I wish to get this result

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done with a built in matlab function.  Check out [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7772-suplabel) submission on the file exchange